# Configuring the firewall with iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have an instance of SSH running port 2233 and a Cowrie honeypot on port 2222.

SSH needs to stay that way but Cowrie needs to be forwarded to port 22.

Port 2222 (running Cowrie) shouldn't be visible from the outside world.
Internal (local) traffic should run as it is.
Every other incoming/outgoing traffic must be blocked.

I have to configure it using iptables only. I've tried reading man pages for iptables & a bunch of blog posts for the last 2 days. I'm tired and would really appreciate any help...

Comment: Are you putting these rules on the server or on a router?

Comment: On a Ubuntu 20 server.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [site](https://talebi.ca/cowrie-honeypot-on-ubuntu/), you need to add these two lines to your firewall rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –dport 22 -j REDIRECT –to-port 2222
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –dport 23 -j REDIRECT –to-port 2223
```